# How do i insert array into database without getting error: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, oop

In m app I have a form with data meant to insert data into 2 tables :payers and Spouses and Payer has Many Spouse. In my PayerController i have

```
public function store(CreatePayerRequest $request)
    { 
        $input = $request->all();
        $payer = $this->payerRepository->create($input);
        {
```

and i have

```
dd($request->all())
```

and got the following result showing that my array is passing successfully from my input form.

```
array:34 [▼
  "_token" => "LDdsaesoaRlKmM0URHVxQqyiJHdrPhLz3lmYQs6V"
  "added_on" => "2020-06-28 11:07:39"
  "user_id" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Auth::user()->id"
    1 => "Auth::user()->id"
  ]
  "ass_code" => "508063"
  "title" => "Mr"
  "surname" => "PLC"
  "firstname" => "ZENITH"
  "othernames" => "A,"
  "dob" => "2020-06-28 12:08:59"
  "address" => "43"
  "street" => "Old School"
  "town" => "Umuguma"
  "lga" => "Okigwe"
  "state" => "Imo"
  "nationality" => "Nigerian"
  "occupation" => "Civil Servant"
  "vocation" => "Employment"
  "phone" => "8035514494"
  "email" => "ugo@yahoo.com"
  "income_status" => "Yes"
  "allowance_status" => "No"
  "acc_status" => "1"
  "assess_status" => "0"
  "approve_status" => "0"
  "payment_status" => "0"
  "authorize_status" => "0"
  "marital_stat" => "Married"
  "spouse_name" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Tony"
    1 => "Nkechi"
  ]
  "spouse_dob" => array:2 [▶]
  "spouse_emplbiz_add" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "nA"
    1 => "nA"
  ]
  "spose_income" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "50000"
    1 => "50000"
  ]
  "child_status" => "Yes"
  "vehicle_status" => "Yes"
  "assets_status" => "Nigeria"
]
```

My problem is that when i send the form with the spouse array it gives me error:

ErrorException
Array to string conversion

I have tried various codes eg

Code 1

```
 $payer->spouses()->create();
```

Code 2

```
 $spouses = Spouse::find($payer->id);
            foreach($request->spouses as $spouse){
                $payer->spouses()->create([
                    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                    'spouse_occupation'=>NA,
                    'spouse_name'=>$spouse_name,
                    'spouse_dob'=>$spouse_dob,
                    'spouse_emplbiz_add'=>$spouse_emplbiz_add]);
```

Code 3:

```
$spouses = new Spouse();
                $spouses->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $spouses->payer_id = $payer->id;
                $spouses->spouse_occupation='NA';
                $spouses->spouse_name = $request->input('spouse_name');
                $spouses->spouse_dob = $request->input('spouse_dob');
                $spouses->spouse_emplbiz_add = $request->input('spouse_emplbiz_add');
                $spouses->spose_income = $request->input('spose_income');
                $spouses->save();
```

And i keep getting same error.

Can anybody show me how to insert the Spouse detail in the array into my database at the same time as i am inserting the Payer.

In the tutorial I am following, the tutor send the following codes but its not working for me:

```
foreach($request->spouses as $spouse){
payer->spouses()->(['name'='$spouse'])
```

I am thinking its  cos he had only one inputfield. But in my case i have up to 4.

My Spouse input is a livewire component with  the codes below

```
@foreach($spouses as $spouse)
   <div class="col-md-10 d-flex">
        
 {!! Form::hidden('user_id[]', 'Auth::user()->id',array(
    'class' => 'form-control col-3',
    'id' => 'user_id[]',
))  !!}
   {!! Form::text('spouse_name[]', '',array(
        'class' => 'form-control col-3',
        'id' => 'spouse_name[]',
        'placeholder' => 'Spouse name',
    ))  !!}
    {!! Form::text('spouse_dob[]', '',array(
        'class' => 'form-control col-3',
        'id' => 'spouse_dob[]',
        'placeholder' => 'Spouse Age',
    ))  !!}
    {!! Form::text('spouse_emplbiz_add[]', '',array(
        'class' => 'form-control col-3',
        'id' => 'spouse_emplbiz_add[]',
        'placeholder' => 'Work Address',
    ))  !!}
    {!! Form::text('spose_income[]', '',array(
        'class' => 'form-control col-3',
        'id' => 'spose_income[]',
        'placeholder' => 'Gross Income',
    )) !!}
    <span class="btn btn-default fa fa-times text-danger padding:2" 
    wire:click="remove({{$loop->index}})"></span>        
</div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: The code $payer = $this->payerRepository->create($input); runs and inserts payers details into db. It is in the next stage of adding the spouse array that i get the error, I am guessing since my spouse data is an array it must be entered in a specific format. Check the 3 codes above and you will see their create functions individually.

Comment: You use a `foreach` loop in some of your code snippets, but instead of using the `$spouse` value, you're using a `spouses()` method? Or you're using the array `$spouses` instead of the `$spouse` value... what happens when you use `$spouse` instead of `spouses()` or `$spouses`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error accurately describes your problem. You are trying to save the array and therefore you getting this error.

```
$spouses->spouse_name = $request->input('spouse_name');
            $spouses->spouse_dob = $request->input('spouse_dob');
            $spouses->spouse_emplbiz_add = $request->input('spouse_emplbiz_add');
            $spouses->spose_income = $request->input('spose_income');
```

All these data are arrays.

```
"spouse_name" => array:2 [▼
  0 => "Tony"
  1 => "Nkechi"
]
"spouse_dob" => array:2 [▶]
"spouse_emplbiz_add" => array:2 [▼
  0 => "nA"
  1 => "nA"
]
"spose_income" => array:2 [▼
  0 => "50000"
  1 => "50000"
]
```

if the type of these columns in your table is **json**, then you should save it like that.

```
$spouses->spouse_name = json_encode($request->input('spouse_name'));
    $spouses->spouse_dob = json_encode($request->input('spouse_dob'));
    $spouses->spouse_emplbiz_add = json_encode($request->input('spouse_emplbiz_add'));
    $spouses->spose_income = json_encode($request->input('spose_income'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It stopped the error message though didnt insert the data. I modified my code in line with your advice    $input = json_encode($request->all());
        $payer = $this->payerRepository->create($input); and now its missing user_id which has been there even when u DD. 'user_id' doesn't have a default value. What do u think is best to do,

Comment: if your columns `user_id, spouse_name, spouse_dob, spouse_emplbiz_add, spose_income` do not have a **json** type, then my best advice is to change their types to **json**, this will fix a lot of problems, and you will only need to save this data 
`user_id, spouse_name, spouse_dob, spouse_emplbiz_add, spose_income` like this
`json_enocde($some_data)`, and the rest of the data, which is not an array, must be saved in the usual way 
`$spouses->ass_code = $request->input('ass_code'), $spouses->title = $request->input('title'), ...`,

Comment: another approach may be a little more complicated and take a lot of memory in your database, that means you have to find the largest array in your data, go through with a `foreach`, and save all the data for example for `spouse_name` column, and for the rest of the columns, which not arrays, save the same data, but I do not recommend this method.

Comment: When i have used this code in my controller doesnt it encode all including the user_id?        $input = json_encode($request->all());

Comment: you shouldn't do `json_encode($request->all())`, you must call `json_encode()` only for data that is an array, like `user_id, spouse_name, spouse_dob, spouse_emplbiz_add, spose_income`, but this will only work if these columns in your table have **json** type.

Answer (score 0):

**you can try something like this for payer and spouse model ....**

```
    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->property =  $request->property;
    $payer->save();

if(count($request->spouse_name) > 0){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($request->spouse_name); $i++){

        $object = new Spouse();
        $object->payer_id = $payer->id
        $object->spouse_name= $request->spouse_name[$i];
        $object->save();

   } 
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  Please always explain your answers ...always.  Why ask php to count the same thing over and over?  Why not just use a foreach and remove all of the count calls?

Comment: i know ... but when insert and update data  simultaneously .. it think it's better solution ... if any suggestion here please give me

Comment: I fail to see any advantage in making the same `count()` call over and over and over only to receive the same result.  Just doesn't make logical sense.  This is not advanced coding.

Comment: ( Product and  ProductImage Model  ) :  sometimes i do not  need insert image or  multiple images for product model  ... this situation i need to check if have any sub images then i will do  operation ...

Comment: Who said anything about inserting images?  Are you referring to a different question? Foreach will not iterate an empty array.  Are you new to php?

Comment: Thank you Abdullah, I have tried you code by adjusting mmy Payercontroller this way:  foreach ($segments as $segment) {

            $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;

        }

 

        return $result;

    } But it still gives me same error. In the erro its pointing me to  Illuminate\Support\Str.php on page 449 and this code is highlighted  foreach ($segments as $segment) {

            $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;

        }Can anybody make any meaning out of it?